# How can I get the column names if the value is null in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table as follows in `BigQuery`,

| VEHICLE_ID | ACCELERATION | WEIGHT_UNLOADED | WEIGHT_LOADED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1000 | 1300 |
| 2 | 5 | 1200 | 1500 |
| 3 | 4 | 1300 | NULL |
| 4 | NULL | NULL | 1400 |
| 5 | NULL | 1100 | NULL |

If the values are `NULL` I need to fetch the column names separated by commas. Example output should be like this,

| VEHICLE_ID | MISSING_FEATURES |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL |
| 2 | NULL |
| 3 | WEIGHT_LOADED |
| 4 | ACCELERATION, WEIGHT_UNLOADED |
| 5 | ACCELERATION, WEIGHT_LOADED |

I've tried write a query like follows,

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG(missing_feature, ','), VEHICLE_ID
FROM (
    SELECT VEHICLE_ID, 'ACCELERATION' AS missing_feature
    FROM VEHICLES
    WHERE ACCELERATION IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT VEHICLE_ID, 'WEIGHT_UNLOADED' AS missing_feature
    FROM VEHICLES
    WHERE WEIGHT_UNLOADED IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT VEHICLE_ID, 'WEIGHT_LOADED' AS missing_feature
    FROM VEHICLES
    WHERE WEIGHT_LOADED IS NULL
) t
GROUP BY VEHICLE_ID
```

But I have around 20 features that I need to apply this operation so the query will be long and I don't know if it's efficient.

Any way to do this more efficient and easier?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is making n passes over the table, which is expensive.

It can be done by making only one pass:

```
SELECT
  VEHICLE_ID,
  REGEXP_REPLACE(
    CASE WHEN ACCELERATION IS NULL THEN 'ACCELERATION,' ELSE '' END ||
    CASE WHEN WEIGHT_UNLOADED IS NULL THEN 'WEIGHT_UNLOADED,' ELSE '' END ||
    CASE WHEN WEIGHT_LOADED IS NULL THEN 'WEIGHT_LOADED,' ELSE '' END,
    '.$', '') AS MISSING_FEATURES

FROM VEHICLES
```

This uses string concatenation to build up the list on the fly.

The use of `REGEXP_REPLACE` is to remove the final extra comma from the result. If there are no results, it still works (because there is no match on a blank string, so nothing happens).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I only got a "Syntax error" because of parenthesis after last `END`. When I removed, it works like a charm. :)

Comment: @E.Zeytinci No problem. Syntax error fixed now - thanks for highlighting that.